# Two deployments with same spec. Then how does the replicsets know which pods they own?

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

Given below two deployments which only defer in name.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: nginx:1.11

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: nginx:1.11
```

Applying above results in to two deployments and two replicasets.

```
kubectl get replicasets
NAME                      DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
deployment-1-8684779b48   2         2         2       34m
deployment-2-8684779b48   2         2         2       34m
```

And the description of replicasets is as below -

```
kubectl describe replicaset deployment-1
Name:           deployment-1-8684779b48
Namespace:      default
Selector:       app=myapp,pod-template-hash=8684779b48
Labels:         app=myapp
                pod-template-hash=8684779b48
Annotations:    deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas: 2
                deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas: 3
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Controlled By:  Deployment/deployment-1
Replicas:       2 current / 2 desired
Pods Status:    2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=myapp
           pod-template-hash=8684779b48
  Containers:
   myapp:
    Image:        nginx:1.11
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  35m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-1-8684779b48-ngm5l
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  35m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-1-8684779b48-5fz94
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  34m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-1-8684779b48-svphx
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  33m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-1-8684779b48-q7lh5
```

And -

```
kubectl describe replicaset deployment-2
Name:           deployment-2-8684779b48
Namespace:      default
Selector:       app=myapp,pod-template-hash=8684779b48
Labels:         app=myapp
                pod-template-hash=8684779b48
Annotations:    deployment.kubernetes.io/desired-replicas: 2
                deployment.kubernetes.io/max-replicas: 3
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Controlled By:  Deployment/deployment-2
Replicas:       2 current / 2 desired
Pods Status:    2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=myapp
           pod-template-hash=8684779b48
  Containers:
   myapp:
    Image:        nginx:1.11
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  36m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-2-8684779b48-w4zws
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  36m   replicaset-controller  Created pod: deployment-2-8684779b48-nfzxb
```

In above, both the replica sets have same selector value as `Selector:       app=myapp,pod-template-hash=8684779b48`
Now how does these two replicasets determine which pods from below belong to them as they all have same labels -

```
kubectl get pods -l app=myapp -l pod-template-hash=8684779b48
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
deployment-1-8684779b48-q7lh5   1/1     Running   0          38m
deployment-1-8684779b48-svphx   1/1     Running   0          39m
deployment-2-8684779b48-nfzxb   1/1     Running   0          40m
deployment-2-8684779b48-w4zws   1/1     Running   0          40m
```

Is the `Events:` information in replicasets output going to be used. Else can someone shed some light.

Comment: The pod names have the replica set name as prefix, which has the deployment name has prefix. The deployment names are unique.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - well I see your point. +1. But is NOT every thing supposed to work based on `selector` else what is the point of having `selector/label`.  Still can you provide any reference on k8s docs to strengthen your point.

Comment: If pod-template-hash of two objects are equal, then those two objects are equal. Selector still works.

Comment: @BurakSerdar - if i kill a pod, how does the replicaset know that it's one of it's pod that got terminated and its starting a new one. Based on pod name.. that seems incorrect. It should be based on `selector` alone. Making use of the pod name just seems too basic. Could you please provide any refs if it's in the docs, that will make my case better when I explain to my peers in my company.

Comment: The replica set refers to a pod template so that it can use it to create a pod. The replicaset knows its pods by the annotations on the pod. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

Comment: well i see it - on describing a pod i see `Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/deployment-1-8684779b48`. So the `selector` stuff is kind of initial filter and it does further more lookup in to each of the pods that are returned by the filter to know the pods owner.

Answer (score 0):

The link a ReplicaSet has to its Pods is via the Pods’ [metadata.ownerReferences](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#owners-dependents) field, which specifies what resource the current object is owned by. All Pods acquired by a ReplicaSet have their owning ReplicaSet’s identifying information within their ownerReferences field. It’s through this link that the ReplicaSet knows of the state of the Pods it is maintaining and plans accordingly.

Furthermore,

> The [pod-template-hash label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template-hash-label) is added by the Deployment controller to
> every ReplicaSet that a Deployment creates or adopts.
>
> This label ensures that child ReplicaSets of a Deployment do not
> overlap. It is generated by hashing the PodTemplate of the ReplicaSet
> and using the resulting hash as the label value that is added to the
> ReplicaSet selector, Pod template labels, and in any existing Pods
> that the ReplicaSet might have.